# Spring Data REST CORS - how to handle preflight OPTIONS request?

Tags: spring, cors, spring-data-rest, http-options-method

I'm using Spring Data REST to build a RESTful API. Until now my HTML GUI for this RESTful service was served from the same Tomcat and I had no problems wit Cross Origin requests.

Now I want to serve the static files from a different server. This means the API is on another domain/port. Browsers will send the OPTIONS request to get the Access-Control headers from the server. Unfortunately Spring Data REST does not handle those OPTIONS requests and even returns a HTTP 500.

I tried creating a custom controller that handles all OPTIONS requests

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
public class OptionsController {

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity options() {
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Which worked for OPTIONS, but then all other requests (like GET) ceased to work.

OPTIONS requests are switched on via the dispatchOptionsRequest dispatcher servlet parameter.

Comment: Have you tried Tomcat's CORS filter?

Comment: No. The issue is fixed in SDR in the next version.

We just used a reverse proxy to map the requests to the same domain and port.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: currently Spring Data REST does not answer `OPTIONS` requests at all.

It might be worth opening a ticket in our [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST).

> Browsers will send the OPTIONS request to get the Access-Control headers from the server.

Is that specified somewhere? If so, it would be cool if the ticket description included a link to that spec.

A few comments regarding your approach for a workaround:

1. `@RequestMapping` on the controller method overrides the `method` attribute and expectedly now matches *all* HTTP methods, which is why you see all requests intercepted. So you need to define `OPTIONS` as HTTP method there, too (or maybe instead of in the class mapping).
2. You're not returning any `Allow` header which is the whole purpose of `OPTIONS` in the first place.
3. I wonder if the approach in general makes sense as it'll be hard to reason about the supported HTTP methods in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I tried 1), should have posted that. Did not work. As soon as I register my controller no Data REST exported method does work.
The headers are added in a filter.

Point 3, well I think CORS is a common problem and should be supported, especially for REST APIs.

Comment: I opened https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-333. References to the w3c and mozilla are included.

Comment: @OliverGierke I noticed that Spring Data REST sets the allow methods header using org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.ALLOW which is set to "Allow". According to this [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-methods-response-header), the header name should be Access-Control-Allow-Methods. Why is this discrepancy?

Comment: We currently simply implement the HTTP OPTIONS method as defined in the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the parameter `dispatchOptionsRequest` to `true` into the dispatcher to process the `Options` method calls, into the implementation of the `WebApplicationInitializer`.

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext));

dispatcher.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");                

dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
```